# Run-time error 1004 on .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, csv

Good morning, that's my first post here ...so please be patient with me :)

I've a problem with a VBA code I'm trying to execute on Excel 2016. I'm running a MacOSX Sierra machine.

Everyday I need to import data from 3 .csv files and put it on 3 different excel worksheets, format data in a particular way and add a weblink, so I recorded a macro on an excel file which does this for me.

Here is the code to import a single .csv (that's the same for all ones)

```
Sub csvimport()
'
' csvimport Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+Shift+I
'
    Sheets("displayAddedByCollaboration").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/oem/Desktop/report/displayAddedByCollaborationReport.csv", _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "displayAddedByCollaborationReport"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .UseListObject = False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
    Range("U2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-3] = """","""",HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.it/"",""View receipt""))"
    Range("U2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U2001"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("U2:U2001").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("displayAddedByCollaboration").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("displayAddedByCollaboration").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A2001"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("displayAddedByCollaboration").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

It works fine for a couple of days and than, unexpectedly, it stops working returning a Run-time error 1004. The code stops at this line and I can't figure out why:

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

That's the content of report folder on my desktop:

```
Mauros-MacBook-Pro-2:~ oem$ cd /Users/oem/Desktop/report/
Mauros-MacBook-Pro-2:report oem$ ls -la
total 2592
drwx------@  6 oem  staff      204 May  5 08:35 .
drwx------+ 12 oem  staff      408 May  5 09:53 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 oem  staff     6148 May  5 08:35 .DS_Store
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 oem  staff    46795 May  5 08:32 displayAddedByCollaborationReport.csv
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 oem  staff    55837 May  5 08:32 eanNotInAnagraphic.csv
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 oem  staff  1210072 May  5 08:32 notCertifiedProductRecognizedReport.csv
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run time error 1004 in excel 2010 Refresh BackgroundQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635708/run-time-error-1004-in-excel-2010-refresh-backgroundquery)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that solution does't work for me :(
In my case, the filename and filepath of the .csv files remains the same.

Comment: The error occurs if there is a problem with getting the file `/Users/oem/Desktop/report/displayAddedByCollaborationReport.csv`. So if you are on a `Mac` (you should have mentioned this), then check why accessing `/Users/oem/Desktop/report/displayAddedByCollaborationReport.csv` fails if the macro fails.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention I'm on a Mac. I've added the output of `ls -la` command on report folder in my post. Thank you.

Comment: As you can see, the .csv is on the correct position. I've also tried giving a `chmod 777 displayAddedByCollaborationReport.‌​csv`, but the macro still does not work.

Comment: Maybe a [Problem with Apple’s sandbox requirements and Mac Office 2016 with VBA code](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm)? But I'm not a Mac user. So probably others will now be able giving better answers to that.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I've simply modified the filepath on the code `"TEXT;/Users/oem/Desktop/report/displayAddedByCollaborationReport.csv", _` 
with this one 
`"TEXT;/Users/oem/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/report/displayAddedByCollaborationReport.csv", _` 
so I'm working on this path now. Don't know if there is a more "comfortable" solution.